# how to implement lazy loading in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 tables with mapping
CompanyRegistration

```
    <one-to-one name="referenceDb"   class="com.hibermappings.ReferenceDb"  cascade="all" constrained="false" /> 
    <one-to-one name="registration"  class="com.hibermappings.Registration" cascade="all" constrained="false" /> 

    <property name="companyName" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="companyName" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="companyProfile" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="companyProfile" length="50" />
    </property>
    <!--<property name="functionalArea" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="functionalArea" length="50" />
    </property>
    --><property name="contactPerson" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="contactPerson" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="website" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="website" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="country" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="country" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="state" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="state" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="city" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="address" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="email" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="mobile" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="mobile" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="phone" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="fax" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="fax" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="image" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="image" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="video" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="video" length="50" />
    </property>
</class>
```

second is Referencedb

currentprofile

```
            </generator>
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="currentprofile" class="com.hibermappings.Currentprofile"  constrained="false" />

    <property name="referencedId" type="string">
        <column name="referenced_id" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="associateCode" type="string">
        <column name="associate_code" length="8" />
    </property>
    <property name="active" type="string">
        <column name="active" length="1" />
    </property>
    <property name="userType" type="string">
        <column name="user_type" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="numericId" type="integer">
        <column name="numeric_id" />
    </property>
</class>
```

and third is Registration

    
        
            
            
                     currentprofile

```
    <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="name" length="80" />
    </property>
    <property name="joinDate" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="join_date" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="orgname" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="orgname" length="80" />
    </property>
    <property name="cperson" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="cperson" length="80" />
    </property>
    <property name="mobile" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="mobile" length="15" />
    </property>
    <property name="phone1" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="phone1" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="phone2" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="phone2" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="fax" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="fax" length="20" />
    </property>
    <property name="address" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="address" length="65535" />
    </property>
    <property name="country" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="country" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="state" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="state" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="city" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="pincode" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="pincode" length="6" />
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="email" length="80" />
    </property>
    <property name="associateLocation" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="associate_location" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="designation" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="designation" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="chatType" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="chatType" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="gmailChatId" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="gmailChatId" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="hotmailChatId" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="hotmailChatId" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="rediffchatId" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="rediffchatId" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="yahoochatId" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="yahoochatId" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="otherChatId" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="otherChatId" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="activateDate" type="java.util.Date">
        <column name="activate_date" length="0" />
    </property>
    <property name="fname" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="fName" length="200" />
    </property>
    <property name="perAddress" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="perAddress" length="50" />
    </property>
    <property name="prefereduserid" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="prefereduserid" length="50"  />
    </property>
    <property name="useby" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="useby" length="2" />
    </property>
    <property name="academytype" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="academytype" length="75" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Now when I am trying to load the object from CompanyRegistrtion table with companyId the child objects of Referencedb and Registration is also loaded and finally
I got the exception..
How can I  iplement the lazy loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate uses lazy loading by default. However, it is explicitly disabled in your mapping:

```
<one-to-one name="referenceDb" lazy="false" ... />
<one-to-one name="registration" lazy="false" ... />
```

Removing `lazy="false"` should solve your problem.

Comment: @saurabh Maybe if you revealed what exception it is (error message, stack trace, ...), that would improve your chance of actually getting an answer...

Comment: Answer posted here, might help you also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574610/in-hibernate-component-tag-lazy-loading-is-not-working/24578112#24578112